# File does not contain a definition for ' regData'

Tags: c#, uwp

I have been trying to download a text file content using Microsoft.OneDriveSDK inserted into my UWP app. But I get this error message:  File does not contain a definition for 'regData', where regData.txt is the file containing the details i need.

```
   Debug.WriteLine($"Content for file {Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk.File.regData}:")
```

Also found an example from Microsoft site, written as follows: And still can't figure out what "Name" in this case stands for.

```
   Debug.WriteLine($"Content for file {file.Name}:");
```

Comment: In the second case "file" (lower case f) is a variable referencing a file and it has a "Name" property. In the first case "File" ( uppercase F) is a class and does not have a static property "regData".

Comment: Very true as i first defined the variable  file as follows:                                  var file = await builder.Content.Request().GetAsync();                                  and i think what i really don't get yet is its property "Name"  i have tried fiew but still get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> File does not contain a definition for ' regData'

For this issue, as @Crowcoder said, the `Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk.File` class doesn't have a static property `regData`. You cannot get a file on this way.

> Very true as i first defined the variable file as follows: var file = await builder.Content.Request().GetAsync(); and i think what i really don't get yet is its property "Name" i have tried fiew but still get an error.

It seems like you found the sample - Figure 2 Downloading a Text File’s Content from [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt632271.aspx). I tested the sample and it can work well on my side and name property can be got. The code I'm using for testing as follows:

```
IItemRequestBuilder builder = app.OneDriveClient
     .Drive
     .Root
     .ItemWithPath("regfolder/regdata.txt");
 Item file = await builder
   .Request()
   .GetAsync();
 Stream contentStream = await builder.Content
   .Request()
   .GetAsync();
 Debug.WriteLine($"Content for file {file.Name}:");

 using (var reader = new StreamReader(contentStream))
 {
     Debug.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
 }
```

And the result:

[image]

For your issue to get the name property of file, you may need to check the followings:

- The folder contains the txt file may need be public;
- The txt file you got should be a `Item` object not a `File` object, [`File`](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/blob/master/src/OneDriveSdk/Models/Generated/Item.cs)class inside one-driver sdk doesn't contain a name property, the [`Item`](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/blob/master/src/OneDriveSdk/Models/Generated/File.cs) has;
- Ensure you actually can get the file by path correctly. You may use the above code snippet for checking if the `Item file=...` has value.

Since you don't give all your code snippet but only `var file = await builder.Content.Request().GetAsync();`. I'm not sure what's your `builder` here, but it seems like you are getting the `Content`  not try to get a `Item`. Content commonly is `Stream` object should not contain a name property. If this builder is same as mine here is `IItemRequestBuilder` object you should get the file object by code `await builder.Request().GetAsync();` Please try the above code snippet with replacing the file path to yours for testing.

Comment: Hallo Sunteen, I just tried it and it seemed true about setting the folder public, and also the definition of my builder was = ItemwithPath.